# Autenticación mediante TouchID y salir mediante segue

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, async, touchid

Puede que mi pregunta sea muy sencilla pero no consigo que me funcione.

Como veis en el código, uso autentificación biométrica.

El problema que tengo es que no se cómo salir de la función sin que me de una alerta / error.

Supongo que al ser un trozo de código asíncrono hay que salir de una manera diferente a salir directamente de dentro de la función

Os dejo el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

```
            let context = LAContext()
            var error: NSError?

            if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {

                let reason = "Authenticate with Touch ID"
                context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply:
                    {(success, error) in
                        if success {
                            estaAutentificado = true
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguePantallaInicial", sender: self)
                        }
                        else {
                            print ("Error")
                        }
                })
            } else {
                print("Touch ID not available")
            }
```

El mensaje de alerta es:

2019-06-06 08:35:46.607575+0200 iAquarium Logger[2039:395543] [Assert] Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
2019-06-06 08:35:46.630308+0200 iAquarium Logger[2039:395543] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo llama a `performsegue` desde el main thread para ello usa lo siguiente

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: “seguePantallainicial”,sender:self)
}
```

y listo el asunto es que estas haciendo y segué en un hilo de background y solo debe hacerse en el main thread